# How to activate help icon when the user hasn’t moved the cursor for long time?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Does any one know the solution for
activate the icon if the user has the cursor inside the same page for a long time. just animate the icon for the notified to user

Comment: add a mouse move function to reset the timer and when the time is over the animation starts and then after the mouse move the timer resets with removing the animation.

Comment: Please could you explain more what 'animate the icon for the notified' means? Also please add the code you have tried so far into your question.

Comment: Are u looking an answer for activating the animation or you are looking for an answer for animating the icon too?

Comment: @ArchitGargi   activate the icon if the user has the cursor inside the same page for a long time. (MEAN SOME WAVES ON ICON)

Comment: Ok then I have answered ur question pls check

Comment: Uh do you mind checking out my answer and accepting it is as right if it does answer your question correctly since the bounty is about to expire in 2 days...

Answer (score 2):

using

> @ng-idle

we can achieve it
using ng idle timer we can set the timer for idle (no UI action on screen) once the idle time is reached(user not performing any action in UI) we have show the UI elements or change cursor style or anything required

```
idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => 
{
          this.idleState = 'Timed out!';

          this.timedOut = true;

          //LOGIC FOR ICON 

          //1) in html add <div [ngStyle]="{'cursor': cursorStyle}"> 
           // this.cursorStyle = "help"

          //2) we add body or any id in DOM
          //(document.querySelector('.main-div') as HTMLElement).style.cursor = 'help'

          //3) using @ViewChild('element') cursorelement: ElementRef;
          // this.cursorelement.nativeElement.style.cursor = "help"
     

        });
```

Full code of ts and html

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Idle, DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES } from '@ng-idle/core';
import { Keepalive } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  idleState = 'Not started.';
  timedOut = false;
  lastPing?: Date = null;
  cursorStyle='pointer'
  constructor(private idle: Idle, 
              private keepalive: Keepalive) {
    // sets an idle timeout of 20 seconds, for testing purposes.
    idle.setIdle(20);
    // sets a timeout period of 5 seconds. after 10 seconds of inactivity, the user will be considered timed out.
    idle.setTimeout(5);
    // sets the default interrupts, in this case, things like clicks, scrolls, touches to the document
    idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);

    idle.onIdleEnd.subscribe(() => this.idleState = 'No longer idle.');
    idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
      this.idleState = 'Timed out!';
      this.timedOut = true;

      //LOGIC FOR ICON

      //1) in html add <div [ngStyle]="{'cursor': cursorStyle}"> 
       // this.cursorStyle = "help"

      //2) we add body or any id in DOM
      //(document.querySelector('.main-div') as HTMLElement).style.cursor = 'help'

      //3) using @ViewChild('element') cursorelement: ElementRef;
      // this.cursorelement.nativeElement.style.cursor = "help"
 

    });
    idle.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => this.idleState = 'You\'ve gone idle!');

    // sets the ping interval to 10 seconds
    keepalive.interval(10);
    keepalive.onPing.subscribe(() => this.lastPing = new Date());
    this.reset();
  }
  reset() {
    this.idle.watch();
    this.idleState = 'Started.';
    this.timedOut = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{'cursor': cursorStyle}" class="main-div"> 
<button (click)="reset()" *ngIf="timedOut">****Help icon content***</button>
<p>
  <strong>{{ idleState }}</strong>
</p>
<p *ngIf="lastPing">
  <small
    >Last keepalive ping <strong>{{ lastPing | amTimeAgo }}</strong></small
  >
</p>
</div>
```

Full working link [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-idle-plwnr2)

Comment: The above code shows an error...

Comment: what error is show?... have you did npm for ngidle

Comment: Sorry I realized that it was some error at my end.. I would upvote but the vote is now locked :(. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Working Example in Vanilla Javascript

```js
let inactivityTime = function() {
  let time;
  window.onload = resetTimer;
  document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
  document.onkeypress = resetTimer;

  function logout() {
    //Whatever you want to do if user is idle
    alert("You are idle");
  }

  function resetTimer() {
    clearTimeout(time);
    var idleTime = 3000; //Put after what time do you want user to be marked as idle. For 1 second you need to put 1000
    time = setTimeout(logout, idleTime)
  }
};
inactivityTime()
```

Comment: I need solution for angular typescript

Comment: But you can call JS functions using Angular, right?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Its not clear what do you mean exactly by hold, and what do you mean by page(is it group of components or just one)

I will suppose that you need to run some animation after the mouse  is over a component in continues way.

solution :

1. add mouseover event onyour component and start counting time while the mouse is over your component.
2. add mouseout event on your component once the mouse left your component you are free to reset the counter to zero or just stop counting and keep the current value.
3. startCountingTime should increment a variable while the mouse is over your component, this variable should be an observable and you subscribe to it. once it reach a certain value you can run your animation

```
<your-component (mouseover)="startCountingTime()"(mouseout)="resetCounter()">
   // your html code
</your-component>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './your-component.css' ]
})
export class yourComponent{
 
  private counter: Observable<number>= = new Observable(ob => {ob.next(0); });

  startCountingTime(){
    console.log("Mouseover called");
    setInterval(function () {"increment the counter here"}, 1000); // set interval will increment the counter every second

   setTimeout(function () {"run animation"}, 5000); // or just do it in one patch without the observable you can run animation after 5 seconds
  }

  resetCounter(){
    console.log("Mouseout called");
    counter.next(0); // reset the counter if you want to
  }

  ngOninit() {
     counter.subscribe( (latestValueOfCounter) => { //if reached 10 seconds do what you want to do })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  export const TIME=10000

  obsTimer$ = timer(TIME, TIME);
  subscription: any;
  obs$ = merge(
    fromEvent(window, 'load'),
    fromEvent(window, 'mousemove').pipe(debounceTime(1000)),
    fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(debounceTime(1000)),
    fromEvent(window, 'mousedown'),
    fromEvent(window, 'touchstart'),
    fromEvent(window, 'touchmove').pipe(debounceTime(1000)),
    fromEvent(window, 'keydown')
  );
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.obsTimer$.subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(new Date());
    });
    this.obs$.subscribe((_) => {
      this.subscription && this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      this.subscription = this.obsTimer$.subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(new Date());
      });
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy()
  {
    this.subscription && this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nxkjbs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)